# For a split second 404 error when merging PDF files

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to merge pdf files and display them in an iframe. Everything works OK, but when I try to merge the pdfs for a split second I am getting the 404 error and after that whenever the file is generated everything works OK.
How can I fix my issue?

```
 <md-tab label="Preview Pdfs">
     <div flex ng-hide="userForm.$invalid">
     <fieldset class="md-padding">
     <legend class="standart">Pdf preview</legend>
     <iframe ng-src="{{mergedPdfFile}}" style="width:100%; height:800px; margin-top:20px;" type='application/pdf'></iframe>
     </fieldset>
     </div>
</md-tab>

getMergedPdf(selectedPdfsIds).then(function (response) {

         $scope.mergedPdfFile = baseUrl + response;
     });
```

The network traffic
[image]

Comment: I am guessing without `mergedPdfFile` is not available at the time. Add `ng-if="mergedPdfFile"` to `<md-tab label="Preview Pdfs">` and make sure its value is null before merging.

Comment: Thank you. That didn't help. The same issue.

Comment: You can share the code that populates the `mergedPdfFile`. No need to show the PDF merging details.

Comment: I added the requested code

Comment: Have you monitored the network traffic to see what requests the browser is making?

Comment: I see that you are not adding the url to trust ` $scope.mergedPdfFile = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(baseUrl + response);`

Comment: I got the same problem. For a split second my pdf merge doesn't exist and then I am getting the 404 error. After that 404 disappare and the merged pdfs appear

Comment: Comment out `$scope.mergedPdfFile = baseUrl + response;` and figure out why `$scope.mergedPdfFile` equals `true`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `getMergedPdf()` function is asynchronous, and you are displaying your iframe before `$scope.mergedPdfFile` has a value.  Therefore, when the iframe is first displayed, `ng-src="{{mergedPdfFile}}` is going to be `null`.  Depending on how long it takes for the `getMergedPdf()` to process, you could be looking at a 404 for a few moments or longer.

The simple solution is to use `ng-if` on the iframe, so that the iframe doesn't render until there is actually something to display in it, something like:

```
<iframe ng-if="mergedPdfFile" ng-src="{{mergedPdfFile}}" ...></iframe>
```

Comment: Thank you. I follow your suggestion but again for a split second I am getting 404( I am merging over 1000 kbs pdfs)

Comment: are you setting `mergedPdfFile` to a value somewhere else in your code?  That network diagram you provided seems to suggest that it's value is `true` at some point, which doesn't really make sense.

Comment: another thought, is it possible that your response is wrong?  have you tried, for example, `$scope.mergedPdfFile = baseUrl + response.data;`